# Docker run syntax

Tags: docker

Can anyone clarify the syntax in this command:

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

I can see that:

```
Host directory: /src/webapp
Container: /webapp
```

but what is `training/webapp`? Is that the image? If so, why is there a `/`?

And is everything after that (i.e. `python app.py`) the command that you want to run in the container?

=====

And to clarify with this command:

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

How does it work if you ONLY specify `-v /webapp` - is that equivalent to `/webapp:/webapp`?

Comment: The `-v /src/webapp:/webapp` creates a volume, while the `training/webapp` is the image that will be used. The command `python app.py` will be run in the container on startup. You can always check the help to see what the different switches does `docker --help`

Comment: And for: 
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
How does it work if you ONLY specify -v /webapp - is that equivalent to /webapp:/webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for `docker run` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

The basic structure looks like this:

`$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

- `-d` let's you run your docker container in detached mode, so you won't see the console output
- `-P` publish all exposed ports to the host interfaces
- `--name` the name of your container
- `-v` the volume you mount `host/path:container/path`, where in your case `/src/webapp` is on your local machine and `/webapp` is inside your container

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/]

- [training/webapp](https://hub.docker.com/r/training/webapp/) is the username and image name for the docker image. I have linked the image's location on DockerHub for you
- `python app.py`are the command (python) and the argument run when the container starts (app.py)

Comment: And in the case of simply ` -v /webapp`? E.g. `$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py`

Comment: Please see the documentation for volumes here https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/adding-a-data-volume

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `training/webapp` is image name. Dockerhub accept name this way only.
`training` is username and `webapp` is image name.

if you  don't use dockerhub(this is image repository from docker pull image by default) and build image locally then you can give any name.

```
python app.py : command that will execute when docker up
--name web    : this will be name of container
-v /src/webapp:/webapp  : this will create volume webapp and mount on /src/webapp
--publish-all, -P : Publish all exposed ports to random ports
```

For more help see [docker run Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).